# Почему округлятся переменная

Tags: c++

нахожу среднее арифметическое всех элементов двумерного массива,
но почему-то значение округляется, а мне нужно чтобы выдавало что-то вроде `4,15` или `6,87`.

использую такой код:

```
sum = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for ( j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        sum += a[i][j];
    }
sr = sum/(N*M);

printf("%d \n", sum);
printf("%d \n", N);
printf("%d \n", M);
printf("Srednee arifmeticheskoe: %f \n", sr);
```

изучать си++ начал только недавно, поэтому сильно не пинайте )

Answer (score 6):

Обратите внимание на

```
sr=sum/(N*M);
```

У Вас тип переменной sum - целочисленный (возможно, int).
`N*M` тоже имеет *целочисленный* тип. Поэтому результат деления тоже имеет *целочисленный* тип. Уже после выполнения деления этот результат приводится к *вещественному* типу.

Для того, чтобы результат деления сразу имел *вещественный* тип, нужно написать так:

```
sr = static_cast<double>( sum ) / ( N * M );
```

Вы приводите значение sum к типу double. После чего, делите вещественное число на целое. Результат такой операции - вещественное число.

Можно без явного приведения типов:

```
sr = sum;
sr = sr / (N * M);
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте тип переменной `float`, и в `printf` указывайте `%f`, вместо `%d`. Это происходит из-за автоматического приведения типов.

Comment: так я так и делаю и переменная sr у меня float

Comment: @Никола Кривошея А `sum`?

Comment: а sum int, в этом ошибка?

Comment: @Никола Кривошея, в Вашей формуле вычисления среднего достаточно привести к вещественному (например, `double`) любой операнд.

     int sum, N, M;
     double  sr;
     ....
     sr = (double)sum / (N * M);

Если же все операнды целые, то и результат вычисления всего выражения будет целым (при делении дробная часть отбрасывается (не округляется)). 

Просто потом Вы это целое присваиваете `float sr`. 

Кстати, надежнее все  действительные переменные объявлять `double`, а не `float`. Потом трудно отлавливаемых ошибок меньше будет.